# MySQL Query for calculating weightage

Tags: mysql, sql

To calculate the weightage of faults i've formulated this query,

```
Select id,faultdistribution, faulttype, faultseverity,
IF (faultdistribution='crs', COUNT(id) * 8, 0) + 
IF (faultdistribution='configuration', COUNT(id) * 6, 0) + 
IF (faulttype='bs' AND faultseverity='ft', COUNT(id) * 4, 0) + 
IF (faulttype='bs' AND faultseverity='mj', COUNT(id) * 2, 0) + 
IF (faulttype='bs' AND faultseverity='md', COUNT(id) * 5, 0) + 
IF (faulttype='bs' AND faultseverity='mi', COUNT(id) * 3, 0) + 
IF (faulttype='lf' AND faultseverity='ft', COUNT(id) * 2, 0) + 
IF (faulttype='lf' AND faultseverity='mj', COUNT(id) * 1, 0) 
FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
```

What i intend to do is;

**If Fault distribution= 'crs' then Fault * 8 + If Fault distribution= 'configuration' then Fault * 6 .........**

As, there are records in database but i am not having any result from above query, help/suggestions required.

Regards

Comment: Add some sample data, explain your schema, remove unnecessary data or something...

Comment: check your database, i think some space in the faulttype and faultseverity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuase you are using Aggregate function COUNT in your query which returns only one row.But     your query is running  for all rows one by one which is wrong.

The COUNT() function returns the number of rows that matches a specified criteria.

Comment: Then what should i use?

Comment: you removed the count() function. only use id.Why you use count()?